# Is there any Vlc Library(.dll) video streaming capacity ?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc, capacity

I am using **Vlc Media Player Library** for making C# Windows Form application. Also, I have wrapper classes for using that library. I am getting streaming videos with **RTSP** protocol.

My question, what I am wondering or what I am researching **is there any network capacity for using Vlc media Library?** Namely for example, if I use this library for 30 different network streaming(cameras), Can I get errors or freezing videos? I am trying to make a program which will use with lots of cameras. Shall I use different libraries(**FFMPEG**)?

Could you share your experience for video streaming capacity or Vlc Media Player library capacity? Generally, what is the reason of freezing in the video streaming?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I am using libvlc for monitoring RTSP server generated from IP Cameras. The libvlc is simple for RTSP access and decoding, and the performance is good, however, I encountered issues of low-frame rate issue.
So the answer is:

**Yes**, libvlc could leverage networking conditions.

**No**, libvlc is not very good ad low-frame rate condition (AFAIK).

Comment: thanks, also i ll add my experience after the project finished.